# Join tables in two databases make query slow? is better to partition db?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, join, partitioning

I have a `table1` in `db1` and `table2` in `db2` on SQL Server 2008 R2.

If I make a select query joining both tables, it's really slow to get the results.

A simple query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM db1.dbo.table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN db2.dbo.table2 t2 ON t1.k1 = t2.k2
```

is REALLY slow sometimes.

I not sure if this is common to SQL Server and "have to be like a rule" to "not join two tables that are from different databases".

In that case... I add to this question that I have one of those db binary data stored on a field and I like to separate from main db to not increase main table size... it is better to partition a db for this?

I tested with two simple tables and still joining those two tables is slow.

Thanks in advance for any help.

..***Update some years later... 24-09-18***

be sure that the fields that you are joining are of same type, size and collation.

Example: some property is varchar(255) and another varchar(20) ... that can be a problem because the engine have to cast one type to another (an implicit conversion occurs) and while sometimes it runs faster... if a reindex or some change in the db occurs, you can see that in some moment the query start to took a lot more time to complete....

If you cannot change the field type to match in one of the db/tables, try doing an explicit cast to see if that improves the query speed. 
use 
`cast(fieldname as type(size)) = fieldName2)`

Comment: Do you have indexes on the JOIN fields?

Comment: If the two tables are on different databases but on the same instance it shouldn't affect performance significantly. There's just an overhead to ckeck permissions across databases. The main reasons for performance issues usually are missing indexes and/or locking/blocking.

Comment: yes I tested with and without indexes... also note that I tested to only put some records and also it was slow with about 100 records (slow = between 2 seconds and 10 seconds)
to me seems like that the fact that the join cross between the two databases takes time or something else

Comment: @Lmu92 I ask this now because about a year ago I ended up copying all the tables from the "shared" database to each "child" database because this problem, and all worked ok, but never figured out searching on ms docs and web why when tables are on two different db the delay/slow query result happens. 

If you can tell me that this not have to be a issue (join on 2 dbs), at least now that I again have to create another db to store data and have to join this with existent db, at least will be more sure that I'm not making something very wrong

Comment: Can you explain why you need 2 databases and not have all the data in one?

Comment: can you post your actual execution plan?

Comment: @ypercube the time that I made another db is as I tell to lmu92 because I have "shared" data (customers, addreses, etc... as a example that can be used on different DBs)

Comment: @FabianSilva: That's no explanation at all. Please provide a better description of he business requirements that necessitate separate databases.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I have a "common" DB with common tables and have about 10 databases that use that same DB. because that, I have to make joins between the those databases and the "common" db. 
Sadly I not have those days access to the place where those databases exist to capture a query plan or something else.

but today the real need is that I want to put small PDFs on a sql db (for easy backup, faster access, common place, etc)
and I'm seeing what is the best option (and remember the problem that I have before using 2 db)
I ended creating another DB with a "pdfs" table joined to main db

Comment: because seems that my *previous* db implementation of common db for some dbs (as answers says) not have to give trobules and is same that put on same db.
I like to use another db to put pdfs on another pyshycal file, to avoid increase the main db size. and seems that it not have to give me future troubles. (I was worried about that)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You've got a bunch of different questions in here, so let's break 'em out individually.

**Q: If I join two tables in the same database with the above query, why is it slow?**

A: For starters, you're not using a WHERE clause, so SQL Server has to build the complete result set, merging both tables together. If you only need a subset of the data, consider using a WHERE clause to just get the data you need.

Once you've done that, note that you're using a LEFT OUTER JOIN. This tells SQL Server, "Not all of the table1 records will have matching records in table2." That's totally fine if it's true - but if you know all t1 records will have at least one t2 record, use an INNER JOIN instead.

Next, indexing starts to come into play - depending on the width of the tables and the numbers of fields, you may want to add indexes on the fields you're using for the join. To get good advice on that, it's best to post the actual execution plan you're working with.

**Q: If I the tables are in different databases on the same SQL Server, does that change anything?**

A: No. There's some interesting gotchas around things like default isolation levels in different databases, but for the most part, your queries should produce the same execution plans and speeds.

**Q: Should I use table partitioning to make this go faster?**

A: You mentioned database partitioning, but there's no such thing in SQL Server - I'm guessing you meant table partitioning. Generally speaking, no, I wouldn't jump to database design changes in order to make a join go faster. Start with the basics - understanding SQL Server execution plans - and only make database design changes to solve problems that you can't fix with things like indexes.

Comment: Also, especially if you don't need all of the columns (and at least the join column is redundant), [stop using `SELECT *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).

Comment: thanks @AaronBertrand I previously have a "Select * " on a view and when altered one of the tables that use the view the "select *" has retrieved erroneous table columnns and have to alter table and save it again to make it to work. in general select * is really a monster that not have to exist 
I only put "select * " as a generic example of join two tables on two dbs.. not more than that.

Comment: @FabianSilva Yes, I talk about exactly that scenario [in the post I linked](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).

Comment: the 2nd answer was what I need to know, not sure why on THAT case was slow to join those dbs... but at least I can know that I was not doing something wrong joining tables on different db of same server.